# Dynamic number of columns in axlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I have `@days`, which is a list of all working days in any particular month of a year. It can have nineteen to twenty-three values. I would like to print them using `add_row`.

How can I do this dynamically based on the number of elements in `@days` instead of hardcoding the values like shown below?

```
sheet.add_row [@days[1].day, @days[2].day, @days[3].day, @days[4].day, @days[5].day, @days[6].day, @days[7].day, @days[8].day, @days[9].day, @days[10].day, @days[11].day, @days[12].day, @days[13].day, @days[14].day, @days[15].day, @days[16].day, @days[17].day, @days[18].day, @days[19].day, @days[20].day, @days[21].day, @days[22].day, @days[23].day]
```

The above line will print twenty-three values irrespective of the number of elements in `@days`. How can I avoid this and print only the contents of `@days`?

Comment: why do you start at `@days[1]`? And then why don't you simply do `@days.map(&:day)`?

Comment: @geoffroy - Thanks much for the tip. Allthough I am not quite clear on how I could use map in this context (which is code generation in essence). I need to generate an `add_row` call as shown in my question using `map` in an `axlsx` file. Pls help and pls pardon my ignorance!

Comment: I tried this - `sheet.add_row [nil, nil, nil, @work_days.map(&:work_day)]`

But I got this error - `undefined method work_day for #<SequenceNumber:0x00007f6231f9f818>`

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start without doing everything in your place, so no.